# xpath how to print more than 1 element

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape product titles on the first product page of Amazon using HTMLSession and xpath.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getTitle(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)

    
    product = {
        'title': r.html.xpath('//*[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]').text
    }

    print(product)
    return product


getTitle('https://www.amazon.com/s?k=amazon+echo+dot&qid=1605730376&ref=sr_pg_1')

>{'title': 'Echo Dot (3rd Gen) - Smart speaker with Alexa - Charcoal'}
```

The product titles have the attribute of class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal", so I want to scrape all the titles of the product displayed on the same page, but the code only outputs one of them.

For ex, I would want something like:

```
{'title': 'Echo dot 1st gen...'}
{'title': 'Echo dot for kids...'}
{'title': 'Amazon Echo dot 3rd gen...'}
```

Any tip or workaround?

Thank you

Comment: I am hard time wrangling with the source, it is too large, IPython is crashing :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have modified your function a bit to actually collect the titles into `product` list of dictionaries (which btw you don't really need). You also do not need `bs4` for this.

```
def getTitle(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)

    product=[{'title':item.text} for item in r.html.xpath('//*[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]')]
    return product


results=getTitle('https://www.amazon.com/s?k=amazon+echo+dot&qid=1605730376&ref=sr_pg_1')
```

Replace the `product` line with the below to get the list of titles (strings) instead of dictionaries containing the the title key and value.

```
product=[item.text for item in r.html.xpath('//*[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why XPath for simple things like this?

```
[x.text for x in soup.find_all(class_="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal")]
```

One thing is this dicts don't allow dupe keys, so you can't have multiple `title` in dict. But you can like `title1`,`title2`:

```
{'title'+str(x):y.text for x,y in enumerate(soup.find_all(class_="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"))}
```